# Graphing / Visualising XML file structure

Tags: xml, graphics, xsd, charts

I'm doing some research with large XML based datasets, and I wanted a simple way to get my head around the (vague and almost obfuscated) data structures but graphing the xml nodes.

I was going to write a perl script that would re-parse the xml into a GraphViz Dot compatible file, but before I dive into that; anyone got any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a tree-view is good enough, perhaps you could try:

```
http://people.via.ecp.fr/~remi/soft/xml/xmltreenav/xmltreenav_en.php3
```

There is also:

```
http://symbolclick.com/index.htm
```